# Problema al repetir function con javascript en ciclo FOR

Tags: javascript

Hola a todos tengo una consulta tengo este codigo

```
    for (i=1; i>=variable; i++ ){
       function formula'+i+'(){

       }
    }
```

quisiera saber como hago que la function se repita automaticamente yo le agrego la variable i pero esta me dice error
SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters
de antemano agradezco la ayuda suministrada

Comment: tienes funciones con nombre 'formula1', 'formula2'...?

Comment: O sea estas itentando crear funciones en tiempo de ejecución ?¿

Comment: si la idea es que tengo un select con numeros es decir 1, 2, 3 etc cada vez que seleccionan un numero este ciclo crea automaticamente los input pero necesito una funtion para esos inputs pero quisiera saber como coloco function formula<aqui el numero generado que es i> y que no de error

Comment: @JohendryParra mas o menos a como entendí tu ejercicio debería ser así creo let tope = 10
for(i=0;i<=tope;i++){
  function saludo(){
    console.log(i)
  }
  saludo()
}

Comment: eso no creo que vaa correr, tendrias que hacer con el `echo <script>funciones</script>` es decir en `$php` en donde si es posible la concatenacion

Comment: que tiene que ver php? @user75463 y la concatenación también es posible en javascript

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters` es que esta esperando `function formula1(){}` y tratas de continuar con `''` o no esta completo tu codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente a como entendí tu ejercicio, debería quedar del modo siguiente

```js
let tope = 10
    for(i=0;i<=tope;i++){
      function saludo(){
        console.log(`Hola soy el numero: ${i}`)
      }
      saludo()
    }
```

En el ejemplo que uso, declaro lo siguiente:

1. la variable `tope` va a ser el limite que respete el for
2. dicha variable tope la uso en el for
3. por dentro del `for` declaro una función que se va a encargar de imprimir el valor de la variable i por cada iteración que haga el `for`, usé template strings para imprimir el valor en cuestión
4. justo antes del cierre del `for` invoco la ejecución de la función del modo `saludo()`

> Por cada iteración del for del 0 al 10 en mi ejemplo; la función se va
>   a estar repitiendo y por ende ejecutando la funcionalidad que tiene
>   asignada

Comment: pero si quisiera generar una function saludo para cada 1 como haria es decir function saludi1{ } function saludi2{ }

Comment: osea que quieres que el nombre de la función cambie y se le agregue el número de iteración? @JohendryParra

Comment: si eso es correcto ya que cuando realizo esto +i+ me da error no se por que

Comment: Cual es la razon por la que quieras hacerlo de esa manera? A primera vista te diria que no se puede... no puedes crear funciones en tiempo de ejecuccion, pero a parte, lo mejor es crear una sola funcion y recibir el parametro. Como la respuesta de Alfredo

Comment: es correcto deberías reconsiderar lo que te mencionamos en los comentarios @JohendryParra

Comment: tenian razon los parametros los recibi por PHP en un ciclo sin problemas mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

Ya te habia cometado que lo que intentas no se puede, ya es autogenerado de codigo, la cual lo hicieras con `$php` pero si solo quieres en `javascript` lo puedes lograr con `jQuery` de esta manera:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="submit" onclick="generar()" value="Autogenerar" />
 <div id="btn">
  
 </div>
 <div id="con">
  
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  
  function generar() {
   var v="<script>";
   for (var i = 5 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    var a=$("#btn");    
    a.append("<input type='submit' value='boton"+i+"' onclick='click"+i+"()'/>");
    v=v+"function click"+i+"(){alert('Formula"+i+"');}";
   }
   var b=$("#con");
   var v=v+"<\/script>";
   b.append(v);
  } 

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar esta operación, debes utilizar notación de corchetes.

```js
for(i=1;i<11;i++) {
 window['saludo' + i] = function(){alert('Hola!')};
}

console.log(saludo1);
console.log(saludo2);
console.log(saludo3);
console.log(saludo4);
console.log(saludo5);
console.log(saludo6);
console.log(saludo7);
console.log(saludo8);
console.log(saludo9);
console.log(saludo10);
```

```
// Correcto
 window['myvar' + num] = myValue; 

// Incorrecto
 window.myvar + num = myValue; // SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand
```

Comment: veo poco viable esta solución por que si fueran 400 funciones que quisiera, no sería óptimo crear 400 pues por ahi dice una regla del software, si estas reescribiendo muchas veces lo mismo, algo estas haciendo mal

Comment: No trata de ser una solución viable, obviamente no aplicará prácticamente en ninguna situación real de desarrollo. Solo trata de ser la respuesta al script inicial expuesto. Si queremos concatenar un entero al nombre de una variable esta sería una opción simple y perfectamente válida.